# How to use Moq to Verify that PropertyChanged is invoked with the expected object and property name?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, event-handling, moq, eventhandler

Using NUnit and Moq, I'd like to replace the PropertyChanged handler code in the following test by Moq if it makes the test shorter and clearer. I'm currently unclear as to how to do this in Moq, verifying that PropertyChanged is invoked once for IsDirty and once for LocalDatabaseFilePath, each time with the expected object (o in the code). Can anybody advise how to do this with Moq please?

```
        [Test]
        [Category("Fast Tests")]
        [Category("PropertyChanged Events")]
        public void FactoryResetCommand_AllPropertiesChangedInViewModel_PropertyChangedEventsFiredAsExpected()
        {
            // Arrange

            string expectedLocalDatabaseFilePath = "eldfp";
            string otherLocalDatabaseFilePath = "other" + expectedLocalDatabaseFilePath;

            Mock<IDataStoreSettingsDataModel> stubDataModel = new Mock<IDataStoreSettingsDataModel>();
            stubDataModel.Setup(x => x.LocalDatabaseFilePath).Returns(expectedLocalDatabaseFilePath);

            IDataStoreSettingsViewModel sutViewModel = new DataStoreSettingsViewModel(
                stubDataModel.Object,
                ReportExceptionAsync);
            sutViewModel.LocalDatabaseFilePath = otherLocalDatabaseFilePath;

            sutViewModel.IsDirty = false;

            // I'd like to replace the following by Moq if shorter/clearer

            int propertyChangedCountIsDirty = 0;
            int propertyChangedCountLocalDatabaseFilePath = 0;
            object? objIsDirty = null;
            object? objLocalDatabaseFilePath = null;

            sutViewModel.PropertyChanged += ((o, e) =>
            {
                switch (e?.PropertyName)
                {
                    case nameof(DataStoreSettingsViewModel.IsDirty):
                        objIsDirty = o;
                        ++propertyChangedCountIsDirty;
                        break;
                    case nameof(DataStoreSettingsViewModel.LocalDatabaseFilePath):
                        objLocalDatabaseFilePath = o;
                        ++propertyChangedCountLocalDatabaseFilePath;
                        break;
                }
            });

            // I'd like to replace the above by Moq if shorter/clearer

            // Act

            if (sutViewModel.FactoryResetCommand.CanExecute(null))
                sutViewModel.FactoryResetCommand.Execute(null);

            // Assert

            Assert.AreEqual(1, propertyChangedCountIsDirty);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, propertyChangedCountLocalDatabaseFilePath);
            Assert.AreSame(sutViewModel, objIsDirty);
            Assert.AreSame(sutViewModel, objLocalDatabaseFilePath);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out myself.

After adding the following interface:

```
    public interface IPropertyChangedEventHandler
    {
        void PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    }
```

The test using Moq looks like this:

```
        [Test]
        [Category("Fast Tests")]
        [Category("PropertyChanged Events")]
        public void FactoryResetCommand_AllPropertiesChangedInViewModel_PropertyChangedEventsFiredAsExpected()
        {
            // Arrange

            string originalLocalDatabaseFilePath = "oldfp";
            string otherLocalDatabaseFilePath = "other" + originalLocalDatabaseFilePath;

            Mock<IPropertyChangedEventHandler> mockPropertyChangedEventHandler = new Mock<IPropertyChangedEventHandler>();

            Mock<IDataStoreSettingsDataModel> stubDataModel = new Mock<IDataStoreSettingsDataModel>();
            stubDataModel.Setup(x => x.LocalDatabaseFilePath).Returns(originalLocalDatabaseFilePath);

            IDataStoreSettingsViewModel sutViewModel = new DataStoreSettingsViewModel(
                stubDataModel.Object,
                ReportExceptionAsync);
            sutViewModel.LocalDatabaseFilePath = otherLocalDatabaseFilePath;

            sutViewModel.IsDirty = false;

            sutViewModel.PropertyChanged += mockPropertyChangedEventHandler.Object.PropertyChanged;

            // Act

            if (sutViewModel.FactoryResetCommand.CanExecute(null))
                sutViewModel.FactoryResetCommand.Execute(null);

            // Assert

            mockPropertyChangedEventHandler.Verify(x => x.PropertyChanged(sutViewModel,
                It.Is<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>(e => e.PropertyName == nameof(DataStoreSettingsViewModel.IsDirty))), 
                Times.Once);
            mockPropertyChangedEventHandler.Verify(x => x.PropertyChanged(sutViewModel,
                It.Is<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>(e => e.PropertyName == nameof(DataStoreSettingsViewModel.LocalDatabaseFilePath))), 
                Times.Once);
        }
```

Comment: It's okay to mark your own post as answers if you figured it out by yourself and there are no better answers.